# Heuristics for Optimization

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, optimization, heuristics

Since it's Friday, it's time for a CW question. I'm looking for heuristics that have wide use in optimization problems. To limit the scope to more 'theory-friendly' heuristics, here are the rules (some arbitrary, some not)

- It should be a well defined method without numerous parameters, and with a concrete running time (maybe per iteration)
- It should have some known theoretical results associated with it (rate of convergence, approximation bounds if any, stationary properties, and so on)
- It should have wide applicability and at least one flagship application where it's either the method of choice or one of a few.
- it should not be inspired by nature (while this seems like a frivolous objection, I'm trying to exclude genetic algorithms, ant colony optimization and the like).

Answers should ideally be in the following format: here's an example.

**Name**: Alternating optimizaton

**Goal**: Minimize a (generally nonconvex) function $f(x,y)$

**Conditions**: The associated functions $g(x) = \min_y f(x,y)$ and $h(y) = \min_x f(x,y)$ are convex

**Algorithm**: $i^{\text{th}}$ iteration starts with $x_i, y_i$.

1. $x_{i+1} \leftarrow \arg \min_x f(x, y_i)$
2. $y_{i+1} \leftarrow \arg\min_y f(x_{i+1}, y)$

**Best known app**: $k$-means, iterated closest pair.

**Theory**: Known results on $k$-means, [general sufficient conditions for global optimality of framework](http://geomblog.blogspot.com/2008/01/important-heuristics-alternating.html)

p.s You might find that your answer ends up as a lecture in an algorithms seminar I'm planning :)

Comment: "it should not be inspired by nature (while this seems like a frivolous objection, I'm trying to exclude genetic algorithms, ant colony optimization and the like)." So no simulated annealing, statistical mechanics, etc. ?

Comment: I actually have no problem with simulated annealing, and when I wrote this, I was trying to find a way to keep SA and exclude GAs :).

Answer (score 2):

Name: iterated reweighted least square

Goal: minimize function of the form $ \sum w(\theta)F(\theta)^2$, $\theta\in R^n$, $F(\theta) \in R^m$, $w(\theta)\in R$

Conditions:  depend on case

Algorithm: obvious - fix weights, solve quadratic problem, recalculate weights

Best known app: geometric median,  M-estimators,$L_p$ norm, compressed sensing

Theory:  proven on-case-to-case basis